# Car won't unlock with remote and won't start? Toyota Camry 1999

Tags: toyota, ignition, repair, camry, fob

My sister gave me this car for school and she told me this happens a lot. Her mechanic friend says it's an alarm problem and my alarm is locked. Unfortunately her and her friend live on the opposite side of the state so they can't help me. But basically:

- The car only unlocks manually
- The remote itself lights when I click it
- The lock button inside my car doesn't work either
- The car won't ignite - no clicks, lights, or sounds.
- My wheel is straightened out

Comment: Is this a stock remote/alarm for the Camry? Or is it an aftermarket one?

Comment: Also, does [this video](https://youtu.be/pBZmwZW1ePE) help you any?